# IF Function accross a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is probably really easy but I need some guidance of getting it right as the sheet is very important.

What I am trying to do is check a range of cells to see if they contain either `Yes` or `No` and if even 1 cell has a `No` then the result cell with have a `No` as there is 1 `No`. The result should always be `Yes` but the purpose of this report is to check if that is the case.

```
Stock Take Done Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes  = Yes
Stock Take Done Yes Yes Yes No Yes  Yes Yes  = No
```

So what I need is a formula for the last/total cell to work this out, I assume it will be an IF function but I have not been able to find the exact formula yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with nested `IF` functions, but a `COUNTIF` is easier:

`=IF(COUNTIF(<Your range>,"No")>0,"No","Yes")`